# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} \ (\sec x)^x$?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} \ (\sec x)^x$?

**My attempt:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ (\sec x)^x =\lim_{x\to 0}\ \left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)^x =\left(\frac{1}{\cos 0}\right)^0 =1.$$

We literally had to just input $x=0$ in the expression, and we got the value easily. Now see what my book did.

**My book's attempt:**

Let $y=(\sec x)^x$. So, $\ln y=x\ln (\sec x)$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ln y=\lim_{x\to 0} x\ln (\sec x)=0.$$

So, $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln y=0$, or $\lim_{x\to 0} y=e^0=1$.

Why did my book overcomplicate this?

Comment: It isn't overcomplicating. At first glance, I, too, would use logs and l'Hopital's rule. Sometimes there's more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Just to be clear, my process of doing the math is correct, right?

Comment: Maybe the book has not introduced the points of continuity of $x^y$... However, in my opinion all the points you've made stand: the fact that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} x^y=a^b$ for all $a,b$ such that $a>0\lor b>0$ is just as well-known as the product rule of limits or $\log$ tricks. It's certainly more basic than l'Hopital. Other details like continuity of $\sec$ are the same in both methods.

Comment: I suppose that they prepare students to go further than the limits. Doing it that way, you will arrive at $\sec ^x(x)=1+\frac{x^3}{2}+O\left(x^5\right)$

Comment: for finding the limit of $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)}$, the general method for more diffcult cases is $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)\log(f(x)$ etc.

Comment: In my previous comment it should have been for all $a,b$ such that $a>0\lor (a=0\land b>0)$. I thought I was working with the implicit hypothesis that $a\ge0$, which I had not mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is “Why did my book overcomplicate this?”.

First, you are right: the book did overcomplicate it, and your simple plug-in solution is valid. I don't know why the book did it in this roundabout way. Perhaps the author was distracted at the time of writing the solution.

Comment: I agree: the 2nd attempt does require several more justifications than the 1st. (And I think that, in such a beginning course in Analysis, these justifications ought to be spelt out, because it is easy for students to forget that these limit theorems do come with conditions.)

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ (\sec x)^x=1^0=1$$
Also, this is most simple problem where $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$. This means the $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$